# what is insert value pattern for datetime field

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I have table call `ProductStatistics`

in that table column types are like following

```
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> CreatedDate { get; set; }
```

but once I try to insert value like following

```
Insert into ProductStatistics(CreatedBy,CreatedDate) Values('20',25/01/2016)
```

I can see wrong `CreatedDate` value inserting instead of true value here,

what should I change here

Comment: What do you see exactly? What is the column type of `CreatedDate`?

Comment: `INSERT INTO dbo.ProductStatistics (CreatedBy, CreatedDate) VALUES ('20', '20160125')`

Comment: @SonerGönül its `Nullable<System.DateTime>`